# MouseHover code for a button in c# (to display a tooltp rectangle message)

Tags: c#, winforms

As question says, the code of my button is pretty basic:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Underline | RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style);
RichTextBox1.Focus();
```

All I want to do, is that when the user Hovers over this button, a little tooltip rectangle shows up "Underline"

Using WinForms with C#

Comment: RichTextBox is usually not a Button.  Use the MouseHover event...obviously.

Comment: Yes, I was aware. I was pasting the code of the actual button (to underline in selected and to-write text in a RichTextBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are using the button to underline the text in RichTextBox. What you can do is, you can add ToolTip tool in ToolBox and in Form_Load just write this code.

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Underline");
```

Instead of 'button1' you can give the name of your button

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried smth like this?

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
tip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
tip.IsBalloon = true;
tip.Show("tooltip content", this, new Point(500, 500));
```

or I didn't understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a ToolTip control to your Form.

Now select the Button in question and set its "ToolTip on ToolTip1" property to "Underline".